# How do neural networks learn functions instead of memorize them?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

For a class project, I designed a neural network to approximate sin(x), but ended up with a NN that just memorized my function over the data points I gave it. My NN took in x-values with a batch size of 200. Each x-value was multiplied by 200 different weights, mapping to 200 different neurons in my first layer. My first hidden layer contained 200 neurons, each one a linear combination of the x-values in the batch. My second hidden layer also contained 200 neurons, and my loss function was computed between the 200 neurons in my second layer and the 200 values of sin(x) that the input mapped to.

The problem is, my NN perfectly "approximated" sin(x) with 0 loss, but I know it wouldn't generalize to other data points.

What did I do wrong in designing this neural network, and how can I avoid memorization and instead design my NN's to "learn" about the patterns in my data?

Answer (score 2):

It is same with any machine learning algorithm. You have a dataset based on which you try to learn "the" function `f(x)`, which actually generated the data. In real life datasets, it is impossible to get the original function from the data, and therefore we approximate it using something `g(x)`.

The main goal of any machine learning algorithm is to predict *unseen* data as best as possible using the function `g(x)`.

Given a dataset `D` you can always train a model, which will perfectly classify all the datapoints (you can use a hashmap to get 0 error on the train set), but which is overfitting or memorization.

To avoid such things, you yourself have to make sure that the model does not memorise and learns the function. There are a few things which can be done. I am trying to write them down in an informal way (with links).

**Train, Validation, Test**

If you have large enough dataset, use Train, Validation, Test splits. Split the dataset in three parts. Typically 60%, 20% and 20% for Training, Validation and Test, respectively. (These numbers can vary based on need, also in case of imbalanced data, check how to get [stratified partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling) which preserve the class ratios in every split). Next, forget about the Test partition, keep it somewhere safe, don't touch it. Your model, will be trained using the Training partition. Once you have trained the model, evaluate the performance of the model using the Validation set. Then select another set of hyper-parameter configuration for your model (eg. number of hidden layer, learaning algorithm, other parameters etc.) and then train the model again, and evaluate based on Validation set. Keep on doing this for several such models. Then select the model, which got you the best validation score.

The role of validation set here is to check what the model has learned. If the model has overfit, then the validation scores will be very bad, and therefore in the above process you will discard those overfit models. But keep in mind, although you did not use the Validation set to train the model, directly, but the Validation set was used indirectly to select the model.

Once you have selected a final model based on Validation set. Now take out your Test set, as if you just got new dataset from real life, which no one has ever seen. The prediction of the model on this Test set will be an indication how well your model has "learned" as it is now trying to predict datapoints which it has never seen (directly or indirectly).

It is key to *not* go back and tune your model based on the Test score. This is because once you do this, the Test set will start contributing to your mode.

**Crossvalidation and bootstrap sampling**

On the other hand, if your dataset is small. You can use [bootstrap sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)), or [k-fold cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)). These ideas are similar. For example, for k-fold cross-validation, if `k=5`, then you split the dataset in `5` parts (also be carefull about stratified sampling). Let's name the parts `a,b,c,d,e`. Use the partitions `[a,b,c,d]` to train and get the prediction scores on `[e]` only. Next, use the partitions `[a,b,c,e]` and use the prediction scores on `[d]` only, and continue 5 times, where each time, you keep one partition alone and train the model with the other 4. After this, take an average of these scores. This is indicative of that your model might perform if it sees new data. It is also a good practice to do this multiple times and perform an average. For example, for smaller datasets, perform a 10 time 10-folds cross-validation, which will give a pretty stable score (depending on the dataset) which will be indicative of the prediction performance.

Bootstrap sampling is similar, but you need to sample the same number of datapoints (depends) with replacement from the dataset and use this sample to train. This set will have some datapoints repeated (as it was a sample with replacement). Then use the missing datapoins from the training dataset to evaluate the model. Perform this multiple times and average the performance.

**Others**

Other ways are to incorporate regularisation techniques in the classifier cost function itself. For example in [Support Vector Machines, the cost function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Regularization_and_stability) enforces conditions such that the decision boundary maintains a "margin" or a gap between two class regions. In [neural networks one can also do similar things](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html#regularization) (although it is not same as in SVM).

In neural network you can use [early stopping](https://deeplearning4j.org/earlystopping) to stop the training. What this does, is train on the Train dataset, but at each epoch, it evaluates the performance on the Validation dataset. If the model starts to overfit from a specific epoch, then the error for Training dataset will keep on decreasing, but the error of the Validation dataset will start increasing, indicating that your model is overfitting. Based on this one can stop training.

A large dataset from real world tends not to overfit too much (citation needed). Also, if you have too many parameters in your model (to many hidden units and layers), and if the model is unnecessarily complex, it will tend to overfit. A model with lesser pameter will never overfit (though can underfit, if parameters are too low).

In the case of you `sin` function task, the neural net has to overfit, as it is ... the `sin` function. These tests can really help debug and experiment with your code.

Another important note, if you try to do a Train, Validation, Test, or k-fold crossvalidation on the data generated by the `sin` function dataset, then splitting it in the "usual" way **will not** work as in this case we are dealing with a time-series, and for those cases, one can use techniques [mentioned here](https://blogs.sas.com/content/forecasting/2016/06/09/rob-hyndman-on-time-series-cross-validation/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think it's a great project to approximate sin(x). It would be great if you could share the snippet or some additional details so that we could pin point the exact problem.
However, I think that the problem is that you are overfitting the data hence you are not able to generalize well to other data points.

Few tricks that might work,

1. Get more training points
2. Go for regularization
3. Add a test set so that you know whether you are overfitting or not.

Keep in mind that 0 loss or 100% accuracy is mostly not good on training set.